# Gmail app Hebrew support

Tags: gmail, hebrew

My Gmail app on the Galaxy S2 stock app shows Hebrew reversed and left to right. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to look for hebfix or RTL fix.  Unfortunately, I was unable to find a direct download link.  Hope this is enough to get you started.

A good place to look would be http://iandroid.co.il or http://www.xda-developers.com/.

If you find a good link to download from, you can update my answer :)